# Error: Command \" invalid in math mode on input line x

Tags: math-mode, characters

I'm receiving the following error

```
Command \" invalid in math mode on input line 60.
```

where my input lines 58-61 are

```
\begin{equation}
\label{1}
\Delta x=x_{efter}-x_{före}
\end{equation}
```

The problem doesn't to be the `\Delta`. The problem seem to come from `x_{efter}-x_{före}`. I have tried to use `$....$` but it doesn't work. I'm new to LaTeX but I think I have imported the correct packages.

Comment: Could it be the character ö that is unrecognized ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ligature `ö` consists of `\"{o}`, which can happen in text but not math mode. Here's how it should be used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \Delta x = x_\text{efter} - x_\text{före} \label{eq:difference}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\text{<stuff>}` which prints `<stuff>` in text mode. [`inputenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc) allows you to specify ligature as-is in your code.

As a side-note, it's best to label things with descriptive names.

Comment: I already had the correct packages so the only thing I changed was \text{före} instead of x_{före}. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Christoph the comment was aimed at `\label{1}` in the question